# Force login into Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I have an app and I am trying to access a secure Wordpress web page that requires a login.  I found some code on the Wordpress codex that I thought would force a login but it seems to not be doing anything.  I was hoping that from the point where the user doesn't not exist that I could force a login.

```
function custom_login() {
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = 'myusername';
    $creds['user_password'] = 'mypassword';
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user) )
        echo $user->get_error_message();
}

function download_page()
        {
            global $wpdb;
            $user = wp_get_current_user();

            if (!($user->exists())) {

            custom_login(); 

            }else{
                return '<p>You\'re not logged in! <br /> <a style="color:#ffa200;" href="'. get_page_link(39) . '">Click here </a>' .
                'to login and download products that you\'ve purchased.';
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Write in your functions.php

```
 function custom_login() {
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = 'myusername';
    $creds['user_password'] = 'mypassword';
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    if ( !is_wp_error( $user ) ) {      
        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
        wp_set_current_user ( $user->ID );
        wp_set_auth_cookie  ( $user->ID );

        if($user->ID == 0) {
            echo 'faild login';
        } else {
            echo 'success';

        }


    } else {

                    echo "The username and password you entered don't match."; 

    }
        die();
    }
add_action('wp_login', 'custom_login');
```